# Open a HTML by tap on an Image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make an image act as a button. I have looked at similar solutions but haven't been able to get it to work. I am very new to JQuery and have been struggling with it.

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.NewEntryDiv").bind("tap", tapHandler);

  function tapHandler(event) {
    $("#NewEntryDiv").load("ClarityENTRY.html");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="NewEntryDiv">
  <img src="jquery-mobile/themes/images/NewEntry.png" class="NewEntryButton" alt="newEntry" id="NewEntryButton">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it almost correct, but you are setting a class name for your `div` element, not an `id`. That means that you access it by a dot, not a hashtag.

```
$(function() {
  
  $(".NewEntryDiv").bind("click", tapHandler);  

  function tapHandler(event) {  
    $(".NewEntryDiv").load("ClarityENTRY.html");
  }
});
```

Please notice that `$("#NewEntryDiv")` was changed to `$(".NewEntryDiv")` on two places. Also I had to change the binding event to `click`, because `tap` was acting out weird for me, it might work with `tap` on your side, not sure.

https://jsfiddle.net/pg6rk47s/

Edit: You can read about jQuery selectors [for example here](https://myprogrammingnotes.com/jquery-selectors.html).

Comment: I believe bind() was deprecated. Instead, use the on() function or just the shorthand click() function for click events.

Comment: `bind()` was officially deprecated in 2016, but it's use has been strongly discouraged since jQuery 1.7 which came out in 2011.